# How do you populate a google sheets/excel column with cells from a column in another sheet in the same document?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, timestamp, google-query-language

I have a google sheets document that has a `main sheet` which will have columns `x` `y` and `z` and subsequent sheets `1`, `2`, and `3` that will each also have columns `x` `y` and `z`. Sheets `1`, `2`, and `3` represent different people who are putting information into the columns.

The purpose of the main sheet is to display all of the information that has been put into columns `x` `y` and `z`in the three other sheets so the information can be viewed all at once. The purpose of sheets `1`, `2`, and `3` is so each individual can track their own individual information without also seeing all the info from other people/sheets.

I would like to be able to automatically pull new information from sheets `1`, `2`, and `3` and have it placed in the respective column on the main sheet in chronological order. I know it is possible to have specific cells display information on another sheet, but if possible, I would like the cells to automatically populate the next available cell in whichever column they are under. Basically, the columns in the `main sheet` and the other three sheets are the same name, and I would like the columns in the main sheet to populate whenever new info is input to the respective columns in sheets `1`, `2`, and `3`. I hope this makes sense.

For instance, if column `x` in sheet `2` was filled in with the name `Jane Doe`, the `main sheet` should automatically populate `Jane Doe` into the next available cell in column `x`. Then someone types in `John Smith` into column `x` on sheet `1` and it automatically populates the cell after `Jane Doe` with `John Smith` in the `main sheet`.

Here is a demo sheet with how I would like it to be, with the columns in the `main sheet` populated with the items in all the columns from sheets `1`, `2`, and `3`: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y0dldFtq6NtLPjU21HVedtUzYKi-MjLTz62tupYbZGY/edit?usp=sharing

Is it possible to connect sheets within a document like this? Thank you so much in advance! :) Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please [read this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/138382) first. Also keep in mind that Excel and Google-Sheets have similar but not the exact same functions. So please choose one of the two tags.

Comment: I just uploaded a demo sheet!

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sorry! Sheet is now public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with formulae, you have two options on chronology:

sheet-by-sheet

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!X:Z; Sheet2!X:Z; Sheet3!X:Z}, 
 "where Col1 is not null 
     or Col2 is not null 
     or Col3 is not null", )
```

[image]

row-by-row

```
=QUERY(SORT({
 Sheet1!X:Z, ROW(Sheet1!X:Z); 
 Sheet2!X:Z, ROW(Sheet2!X:Z); 
 Sheet3!X:Z, ROW(Sheet3!X:Z)}, 4, 1), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3
  where Col1 is not null 
     or Col2 is not null 
     or Col3 is not null"; )
```

---

the next best thing is to have a timestamp script with onEdit trigger so every time your ppl make a change a timestamp is added on their sheet in some column and then you in your master sheet will only collect it and sort by timestamp.

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+timestamp**

Comment: If I were to use your first example, where exactly do I plug that in? Sorry for the simple question!

Comment: @dampfy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DCsdjwGvM9uJUjURPHsijrwzgI64oL2yPMMTEffu8XA/edit#gid=0

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much I am very happy right now haha